# Cannot Link a custom domain to Azure Website from Dreamhost

Tags: azure-web-app-service, dreamhost, domain-name

Variations of this question have been asked before, but none of the solutions seem to be working for me. Perhaps someone has some new insight?

About 24 hours ago, I set up the DNS records for dreamhost to point to an Azure Website. This required me to setup one A record and two Cname records:

A Records:
teletempcooling.com => 191.238.8.26

Cname Records
awverify.teletempcooling.com => awverify.teletemp.azurewebsites.net
www.teletempcooling.com => teletemp.azurewebsites.net

These have all propagated, as verified with the [tool recommended by Azure](http://www.digwebinterface.com/). Yet, when I try to assign them as custom domains, I am told that the required Cname record does not exist.

Here are two factors that may be relevant.

1) The domain used to be a wordpress site that is deployed outside of Dreamhost, which I have cannot access.
2) I had to redeploy the site using a different subscription right before I first tried to setup the custom domains.

Could someone please help - or point me in right direction so that I can get the next level of support?

Thank you.

Edit:

When using Dig, and leaving the Type Unspecified, www.teletempcooling.com returns an additional Cname and A record pointing to the blue screen that I currently see. How do I remove these?

Similarly, using dig for awverify.teletempcooling.com returns an SOA record that looks undesirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This required Microsoft developer support.

I was using an Azure website that I had created, deleted and created on another subscription with the same url. People with more access then me fixed the issue.

I suspect it would have resolved itself over time, as everything was configured correctly, but time was of the essence.